# Intellij 12, GWT 2.6.0-rc1 & Super Dev Mode

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea, gwt-super-dev-mode

I tried to use GWT 2.6.0-rc1 with Intellij Ultimate Edition. Everything works fine except that the Super Dev Mode checkbox has gone in the running configuration. I am not able to create a running configuration with Super Dev Mode when using GWT 2.6.0-rc1.

Do I have to wait until Idea will update the plugin or do I have a chance to get the Super Dev Mode running using a workaround?

Comment: I observed the same behavior with GWT 2.6.0-rc3 and IntelliJ IDEA 13

Comment: I restarted IntelliJ a couple of times, and the problem seems to have vanished. I am seeing the checkbox again.

Comment: I tried it several times. No change in the behavior. The checkbox does not appear. Did you something else?

Comment: Strange: the codeserver works without the checkbox ...

Comment: Intellij 13 has the same behavior.

Comment: I changed some version number in my POM (I'm using Maven), IntelliJ offered me to reload the project. This rebooted IntelliJ, and from now on I could see the checkbox

Comment: Maybe you could try with different projects?

Comment: Which version number are you using in your POM? I also use maven, so may be this will solve my issue too.

Comment: gwt 2.6.0-rc3, gwt-maven-plugin 2.6.0-rc1, gin 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am working with gtw version 2.6.0-rc3 and did not see the SuperdevMode checkbox at all. Also the things Simon-Pierre mentioned, did not solve my issue. I am looking forward, if it will work with the final version.

I found two possible workarounds:

1. Switch to GWT 2.5.1 and configurate the running configurations for the CodeServer. After you have saved the configuration, run them ones. After you did that, switch to gwt2.6.0-rc3 in your POM. The SuperDevMode will continue to work.
2. Configurate your CodeServer without checking the SuperDEvMode checkbox (which is not visible, so it is impossible to check! ;-)). This running configuration is not correct und will not start! Close Intellij, search in the file system of your project the workspace.xml (It is located inside the .idea folder) and make a copy of this file. Start Intellij again und edit the workspace.xml. Loacate your codeserver running configuraton (search for the name) and add this tag: `<option name="USE_SUPER_DEV_MODE" value="true" />` Now your running configuration will work! **But be careful, you can destroy your project! So, always backup your data!**

**UPDATE:**

This was a bug in Intellij. In the current EAP-version, it is fixed.